# How to Search for Space in Php String?

Tags: php, html, whitespace, spaces

I'd like to know How to Search for Space in Php 
For example , I've got `$Studentname` and it's value is John Green . I want to have `$Name` (with value John) And `$Surname`(With value Green) . But i don't know how to search space in string . 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use explode for seperation and than implode for adding space

Comment: `$data = explode(' ',$Studentname);$name = $data[0];$Surname =$data[1]; `

Comment: If fulname split in two part mean one space

Comment: It's would be better to have the user input these in different fields if possible, not all first and last names are single words (some have spaces), eg: St. John, Van Rensberg, Di Estos etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First suggestion:-**

1. Try to take first name and last name in two different fields when you are using html form.
2. Use below code if the above not possible:-

   ```
   <?php

   $Studentname = 'John Green';
   $student_full_name = explode(' ',trim($Studentname));//trim to remove space from starting and ending and explode to break string when space found
   $first_name = $student_full_name[0];//output John
   $sur_name = $student_full_name[1];//output Green
   ?>
   ```

Note:- What happen if a user put name like "John Green smith" Or "John(more than one space)Green". That's why do first point.

Comment: Can you read my suggestion , i worte this as note and tell him one best solution for that also

Answer (score 5):

Using `explode()` without a limit will result in incorrect results. Some first and last names have spaces. For example:

```
$name = explode(" ","Jan Van Riebeck");
echo $name[0]." ".$name[1]; // Jan Van (incorrect)


$name = explode(" ","St. John Westcox");
echo $name[0]." ".$name[1]; // St. John (incorrect)
```

Use `explode()` with a limit (so it only returns 2 items), like so:

```
$name = explode(" ","Jan Van Riebeck",2);
echo $name[0]." ".$name[1]; // Jan Van Riebeck (correct)
```

This will still be incorrect some time, but more last names have spaces than first names. Ideally, if you're capturing the form data, use two different fields for first and last name, but even this isn't always ideal, some cultures have different ways that names work that aren't as simple as first name last name.

[Here is a list](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) of common pitfalls when it comes to working with names

Comment: Already checked yur answer best one for me and give u reward as well. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to split a string into an array by using the space as a delimiter:

```
$names = explode(" ", "John Smith");
```

However, you might want to take account of people doing silly things like putting double spaces between the first name and last name, or having preceding or trailing spaces.

You can use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) for getting rid of trailing and preceding spaces:

```
$fullName = " John Smith ";
$trimmedName = trim($fullName); // Assigns "John Smith"
```

You can also use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to get rid of multiple spaces between the first and last name:

```
$fullName = "John     Smith";
$cleanedName = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $fullName); // Assigns "John Smith"
```

The above code will replace one or more (`+`) consecutive spaces (`\s`) with a single space.

Answer (score 0):

to get name and username from student name follow this

```
$Studentname = 'John Green';
$name = explode(' ',$Studentname);
$firstname = $name[0]; //output john
$lastname = $name[1]; //output green
```

Comment: why two time explode? can you tell?

Comment: @A-2-A happy now?maybe you are the down voter,if you then time to change your vote now

Comment: @devpro can you guess why people giving down vote?I can't understand what the hell is there.
A-2-A thanks man.

Comment: Well my brother first of all dont blame to @a-2-a he said he is not a down voter

Comment: Second I am also not a down voter I corrected yur code

Comment: Third y people down vote becuase u provided the wrong solution and u have enough time to correct. Yur code is looks fine now u will get the reward :)

Comment: Ahan I told u you will get the reward OP chose the best answer. Dont forget to say thnks to me hahahah

Comment: @VakhoAkobia This won't work. The result for the name "Oscar De La Hoya" in this example is "Oscar De"

Comment: Oscar de la hoya not required. Can u explain same name in yur example how it works in yur example @eskimo

Comment: @devpro Some first and last names have spaces. You can't assume none of them will. Have a look at my example and you'll see where this one is incorrect

Comment: @devpro i am giving you reward "thanks devpro" ha ha ha.
I am not blaming devpro and A-2-A thanks both of you.